# Firing an onChange event from C++ IHTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++

I have a html-page loaded in a CDialog in an MFC application, using the IE8 engine, and an instance of CDHtmlDialog. The html-page contains `<input>` elements, and includes jQuery. In said jQuery, I have this code:

```
$(function()
{$
  $('#Left').change(function()
  {
     $('[id$=left]').prop('disabled', ! $(this).is(':checked') );
  }).change();
});
```

Which essentially just keeps some inputs and selects (chosen by id convention) disabled or enabled, based on the checkbox with the id `#Left`.

The issue being: When I change the checkbox from the C++ code like so:

```
// Get pElements checkbox through doc->getElementsByTagName("input")
CComQIPtr<IHTMLInputElement> spInputElement(pElement);
spInputElement->put_checked(true);
```

then **the change event does not fire** (possibly to avoid infinite recursion), and the other inputs never update. Is there a way in which I can fire the change-event explicitly from my C++? I would *prefer* not to require all checkboxes to have specific html-code (such as an explicit onchange="..."), as that would be impractical for maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, thanks to amadeus, I got it figured out. This is the code that works, so everyone else can just copy-paste it if they need it.

```
void fireOnChangeEvent(IHTMLElement* pElement)
{
    // Create a new event-object
    IHTMLEventObj* eventObject;
    IDispatch* dispatch;
    pElement->get_document(&dispatch);
    CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument4, &__uuidof(IHTMLDocument4)> doc = dispatch;
    dispatch->Release();
    VARIANT empty;
    VariantInit(&empty);
    doc->createEventObject(&empty, &eventObject);

    // fire event
    VARIANT eventref;
    VariantInit(&eventref);
    V_VT(&eventref) = VT_DISPATCH;
    V_DISPATCH(&eventref) = eventObject;

    VARIANT_BOOL cancellable;

    CComQIPtr<IHTMLElement3, &__uuidof(IHTMLElement3)> element3 = pElement;
    BSTR bstrChange = SysAllocString(L"onchange");
    element3->fireEvent(bstrChange, &eventref, &cancellable);
    SysFreeString(bstrChange);
}
```

Note that this will not fire any events described in JQuery, but it will get all those that are declared directly in the html as `onchange="..."`

Answer (score 2):

in IE8 an event is created with [IHTCDefaultDispatch::createEventObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752356%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and fired with [IHTMLElement3::fireEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703947%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

For IE9 an event is created with IDocumentEvent::createEvent and fired with IEventTarget::dispatchEvent.

Comment: That requires a IHTMLEventObj, and I can't seem to figure out how to get at one.

Comment: Thanks, this approach worked, though it required a ridiculous amount of low level code to do so. ;)

Comment: @KajetanAbt How do you get the IDocumentEvent? Do you QI it from IHTMLDocument(n)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use **onchange** method (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703817(v=vs.85).aspx )?

**UPDATE:**

No this method probably won't help :( It sets your own handler for onchange event.

**UPDATE 2:**

Try to wait until document is completely loaded before firing any events ( code can be found at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/iehelper.aspx?msg=704899 )

Comment: As far as I can see, that only allows me to change it, but I don't know how to execute it.

Comment: Maybe events are not fired because document is not fully loaded while event occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Well there is an easier way. Bind to click handler on JS side and in C++ do something like this:

```
IHTMLElement *pElement;
GetElement(L"whateverInputId", &pElement);
CString value = _T("123");
COleVariant vValue(value);
pElement->setAttribute(L"value", vValue);
pElement->click();
```

I'm setting a value above (I have a text input), but for your checkbox if you know it is not checked you could probably just do:

```
IHTMLElement *pElement;
GetElement(L"whateverInputId", &pElement);
pElement->click();
```

Haven't checked, but for checkbox this will probably even fire `onchange`.

Comment: This is a hack, not a proper solution, interferes with existing click-handlers, and can easily result in behaviour that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Maybe, but it works. Furthermore this will work with jQuery too.